# Remove uialertview in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

In my app, When I press the home button, I pop the application to rootviewcontroller login class. Now, in the previous class, if any alertview comes and without dismissing it I press home button, Problem appears. Next time I tap on app icon to bring it in fore ground, the login screen is there, but on top of it, previous class alertview is also there. How to remove the alertviews on applicationDidEnterBackground?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105974/dismissing-uialertviews-when-entering-background-state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a global (AppDelegate property or singleton) where you simply store the pointer to the last alert view displayed (and clear it when done).  If the pointer is non-nil, dismiss it in DidEnterBackground or wherever.

Comment: Used this exact solution myself +1

Comment: @D_4_ni Why not? You never show more than one alert at a time so the ivar is always referencing the current one (if any).

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, you can show more than one at a time - just one is _visible_ at the same time. If an alert is visible and another one pops up, the latter will be made visible. When you dismiss the second alert, the first one is still there.

Comment: @D_4_ni True. Though I didn't say you can't. I've never found any reason for more than one at a time. As long as you never do (like me), then Hot Lick's answer works.

Comment: @rmaddy You often experience this with network errors - take Apple's Mail app as an example. When you have multiple mail accounts set up, and you are not connected to any network with internet access, you will get multiple alerts.
You can find a way that works with multiple alerts in the question I linked in my comment on this question (although I didn't test it, it should work)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification,UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification to solve this issue

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(resignActive)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(enterForeground)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

In resignActive method you can remove the alertviews...