# how to hide UipickerViewController in applicationWillResignActive?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I my application i want to hide the `UIPickerview controller` when application enter's in a paused state?

for eg: in my `viewcontroller` i am using `uipickerview`,and is placed in a `popovercontroller`,but i have not dismiss the `popovercontroller` and the application goes in a paused state.
when user open the application the `uipikcer view` is displayed which i want to dismiss.

please help me out with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105974/dismissing-uialertviews-when-entering-background-state/12976086#12976086

Comment: Write your dismiss code in - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSNotificationCenter` for hide the `UIPickerView` when application go in background like bellow...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:alertView selector:@selector(HidePickerView) name:@"UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification" object:nil];
```

and hide the `UIPickerView` in bellow method..

```
- (void) HidePickerView {
      [yourPickerView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe for the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification and when it's fired and your selector is called, you should `[self.myPickerView dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`.
Note: `-viewWillDisappear:` method would not be called when the app is resigning active.