# Check instance of UIAlertView when going in background

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uialertview

I have referred the following links for this issue, but neither of the solutions worked for me:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528929/iphone-sdk-check-if-a-uialertview-is-showing)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105974/dismissing-uialertviews-when-entering-background-state/3181223#3181223)

I think these solutions don't work for iOS7.

So now how would I be able to find out whether there is any `UIAlertView` open, when my application enters in background state.
I want to dismiss the `UIAlertView` before going into the background.

Comment: Both Link are same. remove any 1 link

Comment: I have changed the 2nd link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove alert in applicationDidEnterBackground

Add this line in your class

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(enteredBackground:) 
                                            name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object: nil];
```

And implement method as well

```
- (void)enteredBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        if (mainAlertView && mainAlertView.isVisible) 
                 [mainAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a notification when the app is send to background, so detect that notification in the class that displays the alert view and remove it, that's all

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit, how to detect notification for background in particular class

Comment: @KananVora You can register for UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification in the particular viewController you want to receive the notification.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked UIAlertView property `@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isVisible) BOOL visible` Also while going in the background you get a notification in `- (void )applicationDidEnterBackground:` you can check there and remove all alertviews if any