# App is going to background and enters foreground experiencing blank screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview, uialertview

I have a controller with textview and button, when I tap on one of the textview it's prompts an alertview which contains textbox, OK button, and cancel button.

After entering this screen tap on any of the textview so that it alertview with textview prompts with keyboard.

Now I'm going to background on entering foreground a black screen with alertview and keyboard will display.

On dismissing alertview, the screen is displayed properly.

Why this is happening? Any solution?

Comment: Share the code example & screenshot?

Comment: share screenshot and code.

Comment: @Imad, app goes background and enters foreground

Comment: @user1256276 Add code to support your question.

Comment: have u added launch Screen in project. please check?

Comment: have you added  Application Does Not Run In Background = YES in your plist ?

Comment: How to add scrceenshot to this question? i don't see any option to attach images.

Comment: try this you need to hide alertview before background state : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180789/3901620

Comment: has this problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solutions:

use **definesPresentationContext** to **true**, works for me with similar problem.

In

```
viewDidLoad()
```

add

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

Comment: Tried the same. but no luck